# position of 'only' and the respective change in meaning

Tags: adverbs, word-order

What is the difference between the meanings of the two sentences given below?

1. He plays only as an average player.
2. He only plays as an average player.

I think the second sentence emphasizes more on the fact that he plays as an average player i.e the second sentence is concentrates more on his playing style by comparing it to being average.

This question was asked to me during a verbal test. The question was:

Fill in the blanks:

He **_____** as an average player.(only plays, plays only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To me,** both options are okay.

*However* the meaning of the sentence will change because that's the beauty of the word ***only***.

I'm pasting a slide straight from one of my presentations.

> ***Only*** the new manual confused the PA - The old one didn't confuse her. 
>   The new manual ***only*** confused the PA - It didn't spoil her day. 
>   The new manual confused ***only*** the PA - It didn't confuse other staff. 
>   The new manual confused the ***only*** PA - There was only one PA.

If you observe, the word *only* affects the word immediately next to it and changes the meaning of the sentence accordingly [Another such words *I know* are *just* and *even*].

Let's take *play* as some sport --say tennis. Having said this,

> He plays ***only as an average player*** - Whenever he plays (tennis), he plays as an average player 
>   He ***only plays*** (tennis) as an average player - But he ***swims*** like a winner.

Comment: We can also say- He plays only (tennis) as an average player, but he swims like a winner. But I'm sure after removing tennis the statement becomes more general and so the second one. It seems to me that the first statement explicitly says that whenever he plays, he plays as an average player whereas the second statement implicitly suggests that he might be good at something. Am I correct?

Comment: I had to name that *play* to make my point clear. The sentences *He plays...* on its own is confusing. What does he play after all? Also, take *swim* as an *act* as *play* in that sentence and not a sport. That makes the point clearer.

Comment: *Only* doesn't always focus the word immediately following it.  You're right that "The new manual only confused the PA" could mean all it did was confuse, but it's ambiguous―it could also mean "It didn't confuse other staff".  In speech, we could distinguish these by stressing either *confused* or *PA*, but it's ambiguous in writing.